# How define biblatex entry for phonogram/recording?

Tags: biblatex

I would like in my bibliography to have a category for phonograms/recordings. The important fields would be: `author` (artist), `date`, `title`, `publisher` (label), [some field] (for label number), `number` (for number in a CD box, for example. The desired output is something like:

> Gilels, Emil. (1985/1996). *Beethoven: Sonatas 3--5.* In: Complete Piano Works of Beethoven. CD/LP no 8. Deutsche
>   Grammophon, 453 221-2 .

Based on papageno's answer, my code now reads:

```
%\renewbibmacro*{series}{\printseries}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{audio}{
\usebibmacro{bibindex}
\usebibmacro{author}
%\space\mkbibparens{\printfield{year}}
\setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
\usebibmacro{title}
\setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
\printfield{series}
\newblock%\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
\mkbibparens{\thefield{type}~\printfield{number}}
\newunit
\printlist{publisher}
\newblock\setunit{\addcomma\space}
\printfield{userd}\space
\usebibmacro{finentry}
}
\DeclareFieldFormat[audio]{number}{~nr~#1}
```

And my bib-entry reads:

```
@audio{emil1996,
entrysubtype = "book",
author = {Giels, Emil},
year = {1985-1996},
title = {Beethoven: 29 Sonaten Gilels},
series = {Allihopa sonaterna},
publisher = {Deutsche Grammophon},
userd = {453 221-2},
type = {CD/LP},
number = {8}
}
```

This almost makes it. It however has no ”In:” before the series unit, and no puncuation after it. I also would like no parentheses around the CD/LP nr) It now reads:

Gilels, Emil. (1985/1996). *Beethoven: Sonatas 3--5*. Complete Piano Works of Beethoven. (CD/LP nr 8). Deutsche Grammophon, 453 221-2.

**It should read:**

Gilels, Emil. (1985/1996). *Beethoven: Sonatas 3--5*. In: Complete Piano Works of Beethoven. CD/LP nr 8. Deutsche Grammophon, 453 221-2.

EDIT: the code however fails miserably if there is no series field. Anyone has a waterproof solution?

Comment: I guess it has to with the line \DeclareBibliographyDriver, but I cannot figure the code out. Of course, I could use Misc, but then it would be neccesary to force som fields, and it would make a sorting of the bibliography more cumbersome.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example. I am sure you can handle it very simple if we know your style. I suppose that the following will work `\DeclareBibliographyAlias{recordings}{article}` and now you can specify the field format by `\DeclareFieldFormat[recordings]{number}{\mkbibparens{CD/LP~Nr.~#1}}`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited, and provided a small example in the question.

Answer (score 11):

In biblatex, an entry type for musical recordings exists with the Historian style. So you can make some arrangements in the type @audio or create a new one with someting like it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, sorting=nty, babel=hyphen, mincrossrefs=1, usetranslator=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{recording}{
   \usebibmacro{bibindex}
   \usebibmacro{author}
   \labelnamepunct
   %\newblock
   %\printfield{year} %only with other style than authoryear
   %\labelnamepunct
   \newblock
   \printfield{title}
   \labelnamepunct
   \newblock
   \iffieldundef{series}{}{\printfield{series}}%if true (no entry): nothing, if false: print the field
   \labelnamepunct
   \newblock
   \iffieldundef{number}{}{\printfield{type}~\printfield{number}}
   \labelnamepunct
   \newblock
   \printlist{publisher}
   \newblock\setunit{\addcomma\space}
   \printfield{userd}
   \usebibmacro{finentry}
}

\DeclareFieldFormat[recording]{year}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[recording]{number}{~nr.~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[recording]{series}{In:~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[recording]{title}{\emph{#1}}


\bibliography{test_music.bib}
\title{An example of a personalised entry type @recording}

\begin{document}
   \maketitle
   \noindent
   A recording reference with series: \cite{emil1996}.\\
   A recording reference without series and no cd number: \cite{mutter2002}.\\
   A recording reference with series left empty: \cite{souchon2012}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

the .bib file:

```
@recording{emil1996,
author = {Giels, Emil},
year = {1985-1996},
title = {Beethoven: 29 Sonaten Gilels},
series = {Allihopa sonaterna},
publisher = {Deutsche Grammophon},
userd = {453 221-2},
type = {CD/LP},
number = {8}
}

@recording{mutter2002,
author = {Mutter, Anne-Sophie},
year = {2002},
title = {Beethoven: Violin Concerto - Romances},
publisher = {Deutsche Grammophon},
userd = {471 379-2},
type = {CD},
}

@recording{souchon2012,
author = {Souchon, Alain},
year = {2012},
title = {A cause d'elles},
publisher = {EMI},
series = {},
userd = {50999 73066422}
```

}

Comment: Thank you papageno. I need to use the authoryear style, though. I updated the question above.

Comment: +1 The `@audio`, `@music` and `@performance` types are defined in the default data model. These are handled with the `misc` bibliography driver, which you can override by defining new drivers for each type. Use of the new type `@recording` here is actually made possible with `biber`, not the `historian` style.

Comment: It is really great to learn to code these things. You are really great!

Comment: what is great is to learn with the questions of others ! Everybody wins here!

Comment: However, if i leave for example the series field empty, the publisher and the rest does not print at all.

Comment: I have no problem with this example: with series, without series and with the field series left empty. Is your .bib file well formed (with commas after each field)?

Comment: @papageno I surely learnt much since when I joined the site. Great nickname, by the way; are you really a *Vogelfänger*? `:-)`

Comment: Der Vogelfänger bin ich ja, stets lustig, heisa, hopsassa...